# Intuition underyling kinds of time series that are typically additive or typically multiplicative with examples

Tags: time-series, seasonality, intuition

What is the intuition underyling the kinds of time series that are typically additive or typically multiplicative? From what I understand, additive time series are such that variations on the trend have linear effects (good is constantly good, bad is constantly bad) whereas multiplicative times series, variations have exponential effects (good quickly gets increasingly better, bad quickly gets increasingly worse).

[Here is an example of what I mean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348592737_Automated_Hybrid_Time_Series_Forecasting_Design_Benchmarking_and_Use_Cases/figures?lo=1):

[image]

In that example, airline passengers is multiplicative and milk production is additive. I am trying to understand what it is intrinsic to airline passengers (or other transportation passenger trends) and to milk production (or other essential food production trends) that would result in their time series being typically multiplicative and additive, respectfully.

My question is not about the mathematics of determining whether a given data series is additive or multiplicative--I have ample resources for that. Rather, conceptually, what kinds of real-life time series (e.g., sales, disease incidence, tourist visits, etc.) are typically additive and what kinds are typically multiplicative? I would appreciate help in developing the intuition that underlies these processes, whether seasonality is involved or not.

Comment: Define additive and multiplicative with equation examples

Comment: @Aksakal, sorry, but I am really not good with equations, which is why I am asking for statistical intuition. However, I hope that my edit with a figure makes my question clearer.

Comment: I don't think this belongs to statistics. you're asking about intuition and don't want to deal with equations. it's outside the scope of this forum to discuss why milk sales have linear trend and airline ticket sales are exponential trend. also, it's not clear what you're interested in: the trend or the seasonality? both can be described as additive or multiplicative. so maybe you narrow down your question and make it useful for general audience to solicit a useful answer